# Wordpress Website Server Moving Issue along with large database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, content-management-system

I have my Wordpress Website related [Latest Political Updates](http://SiasiTv.com)

I used to upload `100+ posts` daily and due to which I have 100k+ posts in my website. Database size is 1.5GB and the file size of whole website is around 30GB.

I need to move my website from one server to another. While taking backup it takes a lot of time during which I will be unable to upload new posts.

Can any one provide me some way that all of my website + database is shifted to other server without disturbing my daily posts?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to backup your files and database using a professional backup solution, that allow you to clone your site.

I've personally not moved such installation, but is probably that you will have some downtime during the movement and configuration @ the new server

Comment: This is what i want not to face down time , as i have already mentioned my daily posts are around 100 . So can't afford that. this is the reason i am searching for some optimized solution

Comment: You could go to a special hosting provider which can do the migration for you.

Comment: I am using Godaddy already but the huge volume may cause the Downtime that i dont want to face

Comment: You cna check other providers, or the hosting solution you are going to use, and use their services, could be a great solution.